# Split Python String by letters and keep deliminators

Tags: python, regex

Using regex, how can i split a string and keep it's deliminators in the returned results? I'm trying to split a string containing numbers and strings by a set of letters followed by any numerical value including '.' however it's not appearing to work correctly.

Below is my test string, im using python 2.7 and it's not producing what id expect.

```
s = 'M160.394,83.962L121.5,52L86.31,73.378L58,104.917L89.75,C136.667L158.542,136.667L185,110.208L160.394,83.962Z'
parts = filter(None, re.split('([MLHVCSQTAZ][^MLHVCSQTAZ]+)', s, re.IGNORECASE))
print len(parts), parts
>>> 3 ['M160.394,83.962', 'L121.5,52', 'L86.31,73.378L58,104.917L89.75,C136.667L158.542,136.667L185,110.208L160.394,83.962Z']
```

I would expect it to give me this

```
>>> 10 ['M160.394,83.962', 'L121.5,52', 'L86.31,73.378', 'L58,104.917', 'L89.75,', 'C136.667', 'L158.542,136.667', 'L185,110.208', 'L160.394,83.962', 'Z']
```

It should output a list of strings where each string starts with a letter, found in the original regex `MLHVCSQTAZ`

Comment: You can use `findall` or split on `(?<!^)(?=[MLHVCSQTAZ][^MLHVCSQTAZ]+)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are passing `re.IGNORECASE` as 3rd argument to `re.split` but [3rd argument of `re.split` is `maxsplit` not flags.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

**`re.IGNORECASE` equals to 2 hence your input is split only two times.**

You may use:

```
>>> list(filter(None, re.split(r'([MLHVCSQTAZ][^MLHVCSQTAZ]+)', s, 0, re.I)))
['M160.394,83.962', 'L121.5,52', 'L86.31,73.378', 'L58,104.917', 'L89.75,', 'C136.667', 'L158.542,136.667', 'L185,110.208', 'L160.394,83.962', 'Z']
```

Or use inline mode for ignore case:

```
re.split(r'(?i)([MLHVCSQTAZ][^MLHVCSQTAZ]+)', s)
```

---

I suggest using this simple `re.findall` code that uses almost identical regex:

```
parts = re.findall('(?i)[MLHVCSQTAZ][^MLHVCSQTAZ]*', s)
```

**Reference:** `SRE_FLAG_IGNORECASE = 2` in `lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py` (thanks to comment from @vks)

Comment: `re.IGNORECASE equals to 2 hence your input is split only two times.` haha nice find!!!might also mention the source .... `SRE_FLAG_IGNORECASE = 2` in `lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py`

Comment: Thanks @vks. I have added this source reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = 'M160.394,83.962L121.5,52L86.31,73.378L58,104.917L89.75,C136.667L158.542,136.667L185,110.208L160.394,83.962Z'
result = re.findall('[A-Z][\.\d,]+|[A-Z]', s)
```

Output:

```
['M160.394,83.962', 'L121.5,52', 'L86.31,73.378', 'L58,104.917', 'L89.75,', 'C136.667', 'L158.542,136.667', 'L185,110.208', 'L160.394,83.962', 'Z']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
parts = filter(None, re.split('([MLHVCSQTAZ][^MLHVCSQTAZ]+)', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

You need to use `flags`.Check `re.split` function definition.

Default `re` does not support `0 width assertion split`.So you can also use `regex` module for that.

```
import regex
s = 'M160.394,83.962L121.5,52L86.31,73.378L58,104.917L89.75,C136.667L158.542,136.667L185,110.208L160.394,83.962Z'
print regex.split('(?=[MLHVCSQTAZ][^MLHVCSQTAZ])', s, flags=regex.IGNORECASE|regex.VERSION1)
```